# How can I get how many annotations are hidden in an MKMapView?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've currently figured out that some annotations are getting automatically hidden by MKMapView when zooming out.

I would like to know how many are hidden by one annotation to display this number when the user clicks on the annotation that regroups hidden ones, but I have no ideas how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This code did everything for me :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: annotation)
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "identifier"
    return annotationView
}
```

from : [Why clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations in MKMapView is not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914910/why-clusterannotationformemberannotations-in-mkmapview-is-not-called/47926765)

Thank you for the hints @the4Man

Problem remaining : if Idon't want the current user location you have to set `mapView.showsCurrentLocation = false`
then I can't display user location ... I'm quite stuck there

EDIT : Solved it by returning nil when annotation.title = "My Location"

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the annotation is an [`MKClusterAnnotation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation), which has a [`memberAnnotations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation/2866568-memberannotations) property - an array of `MKAnnotation`s. You should retrieve the `count` property of the array.

```
if let clusterAnnotation = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
    print(clusterAnnotation.memberAnnotations.count)
}
```

Comment: I'm using a loop : for annotation in mapView.annotations .. then your code, but it never recognizes the annotation as MKClusterAnnotation. My list is not empty and I can see those clusters in my map

Comment: @AlexandreBaron Try to follow this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48040945/3151675